Does C have any shorthand tricks?
Something like this would not be possible?
do_some_work({ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 });

You always have to declare the array first?
int array[5] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, };
do_some_work(array);


Does Literal array in C answer your question?

@AndrewMorton - Oh wow, I was searching for awhile so I didn't think it would be possible.  I guess most of the examples online are from older C versions.  Thanks man.
